# Saripaar Validation library throws No rules found error

Tags: android, validation, mvp, butterknife, saripaar

I'm trying to use Saripaar Validation on my project, but it's throwing the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No rules found. You must have at
>   least one rule to validate. If you are using custom annotations, make
>   sure that you have registered them using the 'Validator.register()'
>   method.

My architecture separates the responsibility for handling the view into a class, for example for LoginActivity I have LoginView, which is where I handle my view logic like ButterKnife injection, event listening, etc. In this class I have my annotated fields.My LoginView looks like this:

```
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.ImageViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.text.method.HideReturnsTransformationMethod;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.ValidationError;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.Email;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.NotEmpty;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.Password;
import com.serti.android.feenicia.validatortest.R;
import com.serti.android.feenicia.validatortest.screen.login.LoginActivity;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class LoginView implements Validator.ValidationListener {
    public static final String LOGIN_ACTION = "LOGIN";
    @BindView(R.id.login_button)
    Button loginButton;
    @BindView(R.id.username_edittext)
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    AppCompatEditText usernameEditText;
    @BindView(R.id.password_edittext)
    @Password(min = 8, scheme = Password.Scheme.ALPHA_NUMERIC_MIXED_CASE_SYMBOLS)
    AppCompatEditText passwordEditText;
    @BindView(R.id.eye_imageview)
    ImageView eyeImageView;
    @BindView(R.id.loading_progressbar)
    ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;

    private boolean passwordIsVisible;

    private AlertDialog confirmPaymentDialog;
    private LoginActivity context;
    private View rootView;

    private PublishSubject<String> clickSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    Validator validator;

    public LoginView(LoginActivity context){
        this.context = context;
        FrameLayout parent = new FrameLayout(context);
        parent.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_login, parent, true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        validator = new Validator(context);
        validator.setValidationListener(this);

        eyeImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> handleClick(v.getId()));
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(v -> handleClick(v.getId()));
        passwordIsVisible = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationSucceeded() {
        String action = null;
        Snackbar.make(rootView, "Validated", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        action = LOGIN_ACTION;

        if(action != null){
            clickSubject.onNext(action);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        for(ValidationError error : errors){
            View view = error.getView();
            String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(context);
            if(view instanceof AppCompatEditText){
                ((AppCompatEditText) view).setError(message);
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return usernameEditText.getText().toString();
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return passwordEditText.getText().toString();
    }

    private void handleClick(int id){
        String action = null;
        switch (id){
            case R.id.login_button:
                validator.validate();
                break;
            case R.id.eye_imageview:
                togglePasswordVisibility();
        }
    }

    private void togglePasswordVisibility(){
        int color = 0;
        if(passwordIsVisible){
            passwordEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
//            eyeImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eye_white));
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dark_blue_button);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(eyeImageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        }else{
            passwordEditText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
//            eyeImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eye_white));
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dark_gray);
        }
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(eyeImageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        passwordIsVisible = !passwordIsVisible;
        passwordEditText.setSelection(passwordEditText.getText().length());
    }

    private void showIncompleteCredentialsMessage() {
        Snackbar.make(loginButton, context.getText(R.string.incomplete_credentials_title), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public View getView(){
        return rootView;
    }
    public Observable<String> observeClicks(){
        return clickSubject;
    }
    public void openMainScreen(){
        context.startMainActivity();
    }

    public void openSearchTicketsScreen() {
        context.startSearchTicketsActivity();
    }

    public void showWrongCredentialsMessage() {
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Snackbar.make(loginButton, context.getText(R.string.wrong_credentials_title), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void setContext(LoginActivity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

From what I'm guessing, the library is trying to find these fields on my Activity, and since they're not there, then it's throwing this error.

Is there a way use this library accordingly to the architecture I'm handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `validator = new Validator(this)`  in place of `validator = new Validator(context);`

Comment: thnnxxxxxxxxxxxxx